# Replace ohm symbol (Ω) in javascript string

Tags: javascript, xml

I am using javascript to read xml to a string.  I format the string and take out several characters using replace.  Below is an example.

```
sound=sound.replace(/"/g, "");
```

The problem I am running into is I cannot replace the ohm symbol.  In the xml, it is written as

```
&#8486;
```

I have tried both

```
sound=sound.replace(/Ω/g, "");

sound=sound.replace(/&#8486;/g, "");
```

Neither of these has worked.  I think the problem has something with the way that the xml converts the code into the symbol, due to the fact when you view the XML in the browser, the ohm symbol is displayed (Ω).  Can anyone help me with what symbol or code I need to enter into the javascript in order to remove the symbol from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Ω".replace(/Ω/g, "");` returns "" here. You might be having an encoding issue.

In any case if you think the JS is not saved/served with correct encoding in some stage you can use a literal.

Try using the unicode literal.

```
sound = sound.replace(/\u2126/g, "");
```

Comment: I was just about to post `sound.replace(/\u2126/g, '');` That should cover it regardless of encoding. +1

Comment: Okay, using the unicode did work, thank you. Before I mark you as the answer, can you explain how to add encoding in the JavaScript file?  I did use it in the xml file.

Comment: @illinoistim Editors can specify the encoding, for example in vim it's `:write ++enc=utf-8 yoursoundfile.js` and in WebStorm it's `Project Settings -> File Encoding`. Though if this will be used across multiple files or might be it's likely better to just use a literal and not the symbol itself in case one of your co-workers eve copy-pastes this and gets this bug. Glad I could help :)

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks.  I have never had to encode it before.